# Running Flunt-Bit custom image as non-root user

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, configmap, fluent-bit

When attempting to run fluent-bit as a non-root user, I am getting the following erros:

```
Fluent Bit v1.9.10
* Copyright (C) 2015-2022 The Fluent Bit Authors
* Fluent Bit is a CNCF sub-project under the umbrella of Fluentd
* https://fluentbit.io

[2023/05/02 16:31:18] [ info] [fluent bit] version=1.9.10, commit=010c75b194, pid=1
[2023/05/02 16:31:18] [error] [storage] [chunkio] cannot initialize root path /var/fluent-bit/state/flb-storage/

[2023/05/02 16:31:18] [error] [storage] error initializing storage engine
[2023/05/02 16:31:18] [error] [lib] backend failed
```

I believe this is due to the container running as non-root, and the volume mentioned in the error is mounted as root user, so the non-root user is not able to create or write to the /var/fluent-bit/state/flb-storage/ mount. Is there a way to set permissions for users on the volume or volumeMount within the daemonSet config? I have attempted to add the securityContext for the user, but this did not give access to the configmap/directory.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're trying to run fluent-bit as a non-root user? Fluent bit should be able to do all it need to do so long as you grant it the Linux capability `CAP_FOWNER`. See also, https://github.com/aws/eks-charts/issues/928.

Comment: i like to build all images using the builder pattern, copying in only the required files from the official images, and then using a lightweight base image that runs as a non root user. in this case, it seemed to be too much trouble and i am running as root